# Как в мне задать уникальный индекс для SpriteWithDynamicBody Phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы когда объекты наезжали друг на друга, они совмещались и получался новый. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как мне проверять каждый отдельный объект. Я думаю занести уникальный index в каждый объект, а потом из списка вытаскивать их. Если есть лучше решения или идея как это сделать, то пишите

Вот код:

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';

class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    addEgg(x, y, number) {
        const container = this.add.container(400-x, 300+y);
        container.setSize(50, 50);
        container.setInteractive({ draggable: true });
        const egg = this.physics.add.sprite(0, 0, `egg${number}`);
        container.add([egg]);
        container.on('drag', (pointer, dragX, dragY) => container.setPosition(dragX, dragY));
        return [egg, container];
    } 

    preload() {
        this.load.image('egg1', 'assets/Egg1.png');
        this.load.image('egg2', 'assets/Egg2.png');
        this.load.image('egg3', 'assets/Egg3.png');
    }

    create() {
        const eggsGroup = this.physics.add.group();

        this.addEgg(100, 0, 1);
        this.addEgg(120, 200, 1);
        this.addEgg(200, 75, 2);

        this.eggs.forEach((obj, i) => {
            eggsGroup.add(obj.obj)
        });

        function combineEggs(egg1, egg2) {
            egg1.disableBody(true, true);
            egg2.disableBody(true, true);
        }
    }

    update() {
        
    }
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: Game,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 0 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```